# Disk Check Dual boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu with windows 8 on a new laptop. I have sorted out the flash-drive with the iso, set up with the Universal usb installer.

I have then set the laptop to boot from flash.

When i fire the laptop up I get a grub menu asking me whether I want to try ubuntu, install or check disk.

If I try ubuntu or try to install it gets stuck (installing gets stuck at the screen with ubuntu and the alternating white & orange dots underneath, selecting the try now brings up what looks like a ubuntu desktop but then freezes).

If I select check disk it tells me that one error is found, which is that it can't find:
pool/main/g/grub2-signed/grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.9~ubuntu12.04.3+1.99-21ubuntu3.9_amd.deb.

Having checked the flash drive it seems that this file is indeed there, where it should be.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows8 uses UEFI boot, so follow the 1st paragraph of the Ubuntu Community Doc about UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks for the response: I have followed the 1st paragraph of the UEFI installation, the post was what happens when I follow it.